# Angular 6 error TS8011 type arguments can only be used in a .ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 6 app that I need to include a JS library. The library is proprietary so I cannot get into the specifics of what it is, but the issue I'm having is the TypeScript compiler seems to get confused with characters such as this `<<24>>` thinking it is a type casting when it's really not. Because of this issue I get the following error when I compile.

```
error TS8011: 'type arguments' can only be used in a .ts file
```

The file I'm including, that it's baking at, is a traditional JS file. I cannot modify this file as it's a minified library, and it's not available via NPM.

My initial thought was to just have the TS compiler to ignore/exclude the file, but that doesn't work for some reason. Here is a tsconfig.json config I've tried that didn't work.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./src/js/MyLib.js"
  ]
}
```

I have tried with "allowJs" enabled and disabled, but I get the same error.

Do you all have any idea how I can get the TS compiler to effectively ignore this file so I can just import it with a script tag?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it should be fairly straightforward to reproduce on stackblitz?

Comment: You should be able to do one of two things: Add your script file in the `scripts` array in your angular.json file. Another way would be to just literally add the script tag into your index.html file

Comment: Does the JS files need to be in the src directory in order to be added to the compiled source? Just thinking can I put my JS file outside of the src folder and then include it in the scripts array in angular.json as you suggested. Would that work?

Comment: @mwilson That has seemed to fix the issue I was having. If you put your comment as the answer, then I'l accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you need to reference those types of files (standard .js files) is one of two ways:

1. Add the script reference in the `script` array in the `angular.json` file
2. Add the script reference directly in the `index.html` file

I would go with the first option as the documentation specifically states this:

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#additional-build-and-test-options

> An object containing JavaScript script files to add to the global
>   context of the project. The scripts are loaded exactly as if you had
>   added them in a  tag inside index.html. See more in Styles and
>   scripts configuration below.

I think the issue you're having is that you're trying to use `import` statements or reference the script file in a way that the `tsc` (TypeScript Compiler) is trying to transpile it.

Comment: Accepted the answer...the issue was that I had the JS file inside the src folder. When I moved it out and added a reference to the external script to the angular.json file, then it all worked.